# Ubuntu 16.04: wifi disabled after suspend, must enable manually

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, suspend

Ubuntu 16.04, when I set my laptop to suspend, upon resuming the wifi will be disabled.  THere is no problem connecting to wifi, it is just that each time I resume I have to manually click "enable wifi" each time.

Does anyone know of a way to automatically enable wifi upon resume?

Thank you.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend might help.  Its probably better to ask in askubuntu anyway.

Comment: Good call. I forgot that there was an SO version of ask Ubuntu.  I just posted here because I saw a similar post while I was researching my issue.  Thanks for the link